# Modal image replace with clicked image

Tags: jquery

I've built a modal and wanted to replace the modal image with another one on click using jQuery, but it wont work. Any idea what's wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").css({"display": "block"});
        $("#modimg").attr('src',this); //Modal image
        $("#caption").text("Clicked image");
    });
});
```

Comment: Post the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using 'this' the wrong way. try something like:

```
 $("img").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").css({"display": "block"});
    $("#modimg").attr('src',$(this).attr('src')); 
    $("#caption").text("Clicked image");
});
```